# Excel macro to find the last cell with data then copy the whole page from that value and paste into powerpoint

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have attached the code for the entire working script which modifies my spreadsheet, then the bottom section is where I am trying to write proper coding for having the proper cells copied and pasted as a special paste (to preserve the chart) into Powerpoint.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Autoformat()
Dim WSA As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim Rng2 As Range
Dim lpRange As Range
Dim Rng3 As Range       ' Used for finding last cell area
Dim sArr As Variant
Set WSA = ActiveSheet
Dim i As Long

sArr = Array("Suppressed", "Other Response Categories", "Requires Challenge Response", "Tracking Links Clicked", "Link Name (HTML)")
Rows("6:9").Delete ' Deletes Rows 6-9

With Application
  .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  .ScreenUpdating = False
  .DisplayAlerts = False
  .EnableEvents = False
End With
For i = 0 To 3 Step 2
   Set lpRange = WSA.UsedRange
   Set rng1 = lpRange.Find(What:=sArr(i), _
    LookAt:=xlPart, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    MatchCase:=False)
   Set Rng2 = lpRange.Find(What:=sArr(i + 1), _
    LookAt:=xlPart, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    MatchCase:=False)
  On Error Resume Next
  If Not rng1 Is Nothing And Not Rng2 Is Nothing And Rng2.Row > rng1.Row Then
    WSA.Rows(rng1.Row & ":" & Rng2.Row - 1).Delete
  ElseIf Not rng1 Is Nothing And Rng2 Is Nothing Then
    WSA.Rows(rng1.Row).Delete
  End If
Next i
Set lpRange = WSA.UsedRange
Set Rng2 = lpRange.Find(What:=sArr(i), _
    LookAt:=xlPart, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    MatchCase:=False)

If Not Rng2 Is Nothing Then
 WSA.Rows(Rng2.Row & ":" & Rows.Count).Clear
End If

With Application
  .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  .ScreenUpdating = True
  .DisplayAlerts = True
  .EnableEvents = True
End With

'Ends Working Format Script
'Begin Attempts at autocopy as table and put into powerpoint

    Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

    ' Set range and find last cell
    Set Rng3 = WSA.Rows(1).Find("*", WSA.[A1], xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    If Not Rng3 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Rng3 contains " & Rng3.Address(0, 0)
    Else
        MsgBox WSA.Name & " row1 is completely empty", vbCritical
    End If

' Find last cell and copy entire spreadsheet
WSA.Range("A1:Rng3").CopyPicture

' Create instance of PowerPoint
Set PPApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")

' For automation to work, PowerPoint must be visible
PPApp.Visible = True

' Create a presentation
Set PPPres = PPApp.Presentations.Add

' Some PowerPoint actions work best in normal slide view
PPApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide

' Add first slide to presentation
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)

' Reference active slide
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides _
    (PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)

' Paste special the chart
PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial

' Align the pasted range
PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True


End Sub
```

Right now the script opens powerpoint, creates a new slide, and pastes an object as a picture but it doesn't collect the correct cell values beforehand.

Where am I in error or how can I rewrite this to achieve what I'm going for? The whole top section of the code pertains to formatting a pre-existing excel document that is imported (which works perfectly so far) but I am trying to get the bottom section functional.

Comment: `WSA.Range("A1:Rng3").CopyPicture` is a problem, you need `WSA.Range(WSA.Range("A1"),Rng3).CopyPicture`

Answer (score 0):

Rng3 is a VBA variable as opposed to a Cell address

```
WSA.Range("A1:Rng3").CopyPicture
```

You need to pass the two cells as two seperate parameters
This should work

```
WSA.Range("A1",Rng3).CopyPicture
```

Although I'd have done it by storing the A1 cell as a VBA variable

```
Dim CellA1 As Range
Set CellA1 =WSA.Range("A1")
```

And then passing the two Ranges as parameters

```
WSA.Range(CellA1,Rng3).CopyPicture
```

For fuller details about Worksheet.Range(Cell1) and Worksheet.Range(Cell1,Cell2)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836512%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: I tried using the above format that you suggested and I'm finding that  it does not paste, and it is literally copying "WSA.Range(CellA1,Rng3).CopyPicture" instead of the range. Where could I be going wrong?